# Android: Getting string from cursor following a raw query in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get a string back from a raw query to my SQLITE database.

The issue is that I am bridging two tables, so I'm not sure how to call the column which contains the color (the value needed).

How can I get the string value being returned from the SQL query to my result `variable`?

```
public String studentColor(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    String queryStudent = "SELECT students.color FROM students, comments WHERE comments.author = students.name;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryStudent, null);
    String result = // get students.color from cursor;
    return result
}
```

Thanks

EDIT

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.me.echoboard, PID: 21552
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213) 
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
                   Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
                      at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                      at com.example.me.echoboard.DBHandler.studentColor(DBHandler.java:121)
                      at com.example.me.echoboard.login.onClick(login.java:37)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213) 
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: what does `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method show? what do you see on the `logcat`?

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0`. Your cursor is **empty**. So you can't even move to its first record, since it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not moving within the cursor so it's at position -1 (before the first row)

Use the following this moves to the first row in the cursor (if there is one, if not an empty string will be returned) :-

```
public String studentColor(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String result = ""; 

    String queryStudent = "SELECT students.color FROM students, comments WHERE comments.author = students.name;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryStudent, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("students.color"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result
}
```

Comment: @pskink thks, need to visit the optician again :)

Comment: for one small dot??? it does not pay off ;-) but seriously its better to use `DatabaseUtils#stringForQuery` in such cases - i think it makes exactly the same thing - i did not use it though...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change your query with this and then cursor

```
"SELECT students.color as color FROM students, comments WHERE comments.author = students.name;";
```

Cursor

```
String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("color"));
```